# Calculating an imaginary crossing point between camera forward and object's y-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, trigonometry

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code.

Players are able to place a wall and adjust its height by looking up with their camera. That's the simplest way I can describe it.

```
// Calculate the direction vector from the camera to the wall

wallToCameraDirection = wallParent.transform.position - this.transform.position;

// Calculate the angle between the camera's forward vector and the direction vector
float angle = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Angle(this.transform.forward, wallToCameraDirection));

// Get the object-to-camera distance
float objectToCameraDistance = Vector3.Distance(wallParent.transform.position, this.transform.position);

// Use trigonometry to find the imaginary line going up from the object (object-up-line)
float objectUpLine = objectToCameraDistance / Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

// Calculate the imaginary crossing point
Vector3 crossingPoint = new Vector3(wallAnchor.transform.position.x, wallAnchor.transform.position.y + objectUpLine, wallAnchor.transform.position.z);
//Vector3 crossingPoint = wallParent.transform.position + surfaceNormal * objectUpLine;

// Use the crossingPoint to set the height of wallAnchor
float distanceToCrossingPoint = Vector3.Distance(wallParent.transform.position, crossingPoint);
wallAnchor.transform.localScale = new Vector3(wallAnchor.transform.localScale.x, distanceToCrossingPoint, wallAnchor.transform.localScale.z);

// Use the crossingPoint for further calculations or positioning
Debug.DrawLine(wallParent.transform.position, crossingPoint, Color.green);

Vector3 endPosition = transform.position + transform.forward * 10f;
Debug.DrawLine(this.transform.position, endPosition, Color.red);
```

[image: Edit: I realized a visual might be helpful here]

In my code I'm trying to use trigonometry to calculate the height of the wall based on the angle players are looking at it. Currently, the green debug line showing the calculated crossingpoint is way too high. My main problem is that the last time I was taught trigonometry was in high school and I'm pushing 30 this year, so to say the knowledge is way in the back is a bit of an understatement, and I'm struggling to find out what I'm doing wrong with my calculations.

Some notes: the object can be angled on different surfaces, so it's y-axis may not always correspond to the world's y-axis.

For example
[image: For example]